# Convert flat array of objects into nested array of objects

Tags: javascript

Original JSON data (flat table):

```
[
    {"id":"1","first_name":"Jason","last_name":"Martin","start_date":"1996-07-25","end_date":"2006-07-25","salary":"1234.56","city":"Toronto","description":"Programmer","department":"Finance","active":"1"},
    {"id":"2","first_name":"Alison","last_name":"Mathews","start_date":"1976-03-21","end_date":"1986-02-21","salary":"6661.78","city":"Vancouver","description":"Tester","department":"Finance","active":"1"},
    {"id":"3","first_name":"James","last_name":"Smith","start_date":"1978-12-12","end_date":"1990-03-15","salary":"6544.78","city":"Vancouver","description":"Tester","department":"QA","active":"1"},
    {"id":"4","first_name":"Celia","last_name":"Rice","start_date":"1982-10-24","end_date":"1999-04-21","salary":"2344.78","city":"Vancouver","description":"Manager","department":"HR","active":"1"},
    {"id":"5","first_name":"Robert","last_name":"Black","start_date":"1984-01-15","end_date":"1998-08-08","salary":"2334.78","city":"Vancouver","description":"Tester","department":"IT","active":"1"},
    {"id":"6","first_name":"Linda","last_name":"Green","start_date":"1987-07-30","end_date":"1996-01-04","salary":"4322.78","city":"New York","description":"Tester","department":"QA","active":"1"},
    {"id":"7","first_name":"David","last_name":"Larry","start_date":"1990-12-31","end_date":"1998-02-12","salary":"7897.78","city":"New York","description":"Manager","department":"HR","active":"1"}
]
```

I need to call the function like this:

```
nest(data,["city","description","department"])
```

The first parameter is the entire dataset, the second is an array of columns which define the nesting level.

Expected JSON output:

```
[
{key: "city", value: "Toronto", count: 1, children:
    [
        {key: "description", value: "Programmer", count: 1, children:
            [
                {key: "department", value: "Finance", count: 1}
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{key: "city", value: "Vancouver", count: 2, children: 
    [
        {key: "description", value: "Tester", count: 3, children:
            [
                {key: "department", value: "Finance", count: 1},
                {key: "department", value: "QA", count: 1},
                {key: "department", value: "IT", count: 1}
            ]
        },
        {key: "description", value: "Manager", count: 1}
    ]
},

{key: "city", value: "New York", count: 2, children:
    [
        {key: "description", value: "Tester", count: 1, children:
            [
                {key: "department", value: "QA", count: 1}
            ]
        },
        {key: "description", value: "Manager", count: 1, children:
            [
                {key: "department", value: "HR", count: 1}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

]

I've tried writing a few recursive functions but keep getting stuck when I have to dynamically search the tree to avoid duplication.

Comment: Why `{key: "department", value: "Finance", count: 1}` instead of `{key: "department", value: "Finance", count: 0}`?   That node has no children.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]; please read the [faq].

Comment: What is count? It is 1 even when children is zero?

Comment: @esskar - I currently have a recursive function that doesn't work because I would need a sort of xpath syntax to check if an element already exists in the tree

Comment: @zzzzBov - Sorry if this question seemed convoluted, I can post the broken code I have

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thought this was a fun little question, so I did it... but, I do agree with the people who asked "what have you tried so far". Typically, you should talk about a *specific* problem.

```
// Groups a flat array into a tree. 
// "data" is the flat array.
// "keys" is an array of properties to group on.
function groupBy(data, keys) { 

    if (keys.length == 0) return data;

    // The current key to perform the grouping on:
    var key = keys[0];

    // Loop through the data and construct buckets for
    // all of the unique keys:
    var groups = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        var row = data[i];
        var groupValue = row[key];

        if (groups[groupValue] == undefined)
        {
            groups[groupValue] = new Array();
        }

        groups[groupValue].push(row);
    }

    // Remove the first element from the groups array:
    keys.reverse();
    keys.pop()
    keys.reverse();

    // If there are no more keys left, we're done:
    if (keys.length == 0) return groups;

    // Otherwise, handle further groupings:
    for (var group in groups)
    {
        groups[group] = groupBy(groups[group], keys.slice());
    }

    return groups;
}
```

Call the method like this:

```
var groupedData = groupBy(data, ["city","description","department"]);
```

The output from this method for your data looks like this:

```
{
    "Toronto": {
        "Programmer": {
            "Finance": [
                {
                    "id": "1", "first_name": "Jason", "last_name": "Martin", "start_date": "1996-07-25", "end_date": "2006-07-25", "salary": "1234.56", "city": "Toronto", "description": "Programmer", "department": "Finance", "active": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "Vancouver": {
        "Tester": {
            "Finance": [
                {
                    "id": "2", "first_name": "Alison", "last_name": "Mathews", "start_date": "1976-03-21", "end_date": "1986-02-21", "salary": "6661.78", "city": "Vancouver", "description": "Tester", "department": "Finance", "active": "1"
                }
            ],
            "QA": [
                {
                    "id": "3", "first_name": "James", "last_name": "Smith", "start_date": "1978-12-12", "end_date": "1990-03-15", "salary": "6544.78", "city": "Vancouver", "description": "Tester", "department": "QA", "active": "1"
                }
            ],
            "IT": [
                {
                    "id": "5", "first_name": "Robert",  "last_name": "Black", "start_date": "1984-01-15", "end_date": "1998-08-08", "salary": "2334.78", "city": "Vancouver", "description": "Tester", "department": "IT", "active": "1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Manager": {
            "HR": [
                {
                    "id": "4", "first_name": "Celia", "last_name": "Rice", "start_date": "1982-10-24", "end_date": "1999-04-21", "salary": "2344.78", "city": "Vancouver", "description": "Manager", "department": "HR", "active": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "New York": {
        "Tester": {
            "QA": [
                {
                    "id": "6", "first_name": "Linda", "last_name": "Green", "start_date": "1987-07-30", "end_date": "1996-01-04", "salary": "4322.78", "city": "New York", "description": "Tester", "department": "QA", "active": "1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Manager": {
            "HR": [
                {
                    "id": "7", "first_name": "David", "last_name": "Larry", "start_date": "1990-12-31", "end_date": "1998-02-12", "salary": "7897.78", "city": "New York", "description": "Manager", "department": "HR", "active": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Because the groups are all javascript objects, you don't need that "count" member. You can simply use the .length property of the array(s).

Loop through the groups using javascript's `for (var group in groups)` syntax.

Comment: A nice solution, saving for later.

Comment: Thanks for the great post. I have a similar issue and will try to use your method. See my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63878287/how-to-create-a-nested-array-of-objects-from-flat-array-of-objects

Answer (score 8):

You might take a look at the `nest()` operator from D3.js: 
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/48ad44fdeef32b518c6271bb99a9aed376c1a1d6/src/arrays/nest.js
This is part of D3, a larger library, but looking quickly at the code I just linked to, I don't think this has any dependencies, so you should be able to lift the code here for use in your own project. Usage is [described here in the docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-_nest) - you chain `.key()` methods to define the keys for each layer of the nested structure. In your case, this might look like:

```
data = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.city })
    .key(function(d) { return d.description })
    .entries(data);
```

The structure this spits out is a little different from what you have, but it's functionally quite similar:

```
[
  {
    "key": "Toronto", 
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "Programmer", 
        "values": [
          {
            "active": "1", 
            "city": "Toronto", 
            "department": "Finance", 
            "description": "Programmer", 
            "end_date": "2006-07-25", 
            "first_name": "Jason", 
            "id": "1", 
            "last_name": "Martin", 
            "salary": "1234.56", 
            "start_date": "1996-07-25"
          },
          // etc ...
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  // etc ...
]
```

Comment: +1 Good one... has a couple benefits over the quick-and-dirty version I put together, including; developer-selectable keys (meaning it would be easy to make the keys case-insensitive or calculated), and sorting. Personally, I'd probably tweak my version to add those features instead of brining in (yet another) library... but nice find!

Comment: Thanks - you don't need the whole library, just the function in the code I linked to, which doesn't have any D3 dependencies. But it's true that it might be overkill for some projects.

Comment: I will definitely take a look at this, nice find!

Comment: Awesome this is exactly what I needed. Definitely the cleanest approach possible.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the example provided by @nrabinowitz, here's the nest function with the originally proposed API of passing the collection and an array of property names as args, using d3.nest under the hood:

```
function nest(data, keys) {
  var nest = d3.nest();
  keys.forEach(function(k) { 
    nest.key(function(d) {
      return d[k];
    })
  });
  return nest.entries(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/nesthydrationjs

```
const NestHydrationJS = require('nesthydrationjs')();
function getNestHydrationJS (results) {
  return  NestHydrationJS.nest(results);
}
```