# How to create a nested array of objects from flat array of objects?

Tags: arrays, json, object, nested

I am still learning and need some guidance on how to form a complex nested array of objects from a JSON flat file.

Here is the current input:

```
[
{"id":"US-AL","state":"Alabama","industry":"All","category":"Cable Related Services","itemid":"12290","item":"Basic Cable Services","answer":"Exempt","explanation":"The sale of these services is not subject to sales tax.","citation":"Ala. Code sec. 40-23-1; Ala. Code sec. 40-23-2"},
{"id":"US-AL","state":"Alabama","industry":"All","category":"Cable Related Services","itemid":"12291","item":"Pay Per View","answer":"Exempt","explanation":"The sale of these services is not subject to sales tax.","citation":"Ala. Code sec. 40-23-1; Ala. Code sec. 40-23-2"},
{"id":"US-AL","state":"Alabama","industry":"Retail","category":"Sales Tax Holidays","itemid":"12524","item":"All Disaster Preparedness Supply","answer":"Exempt","explanation":"Alabama provides for an annual state sales tax holiday for severe weather preparedness items. Counties and municipalities are allowed to provide an exemption from local sales and use taxes from the same items during the same weekend as the state holiday.","citation":"Ala. Admin. Code r. 810-6-3-.66."},
{"id":"US-AL","state":"Alabama","industry":"Retail","category":"Sales Tax Holidays","itemid":"12525","item":"All Energy star qualified products","answer":"N/A","explanation":"Alabama does not provide a sales tax holiday for energy efficient products.","citation":"N/A"}
]
```

Here is the format I want it in:

```
[
   {
    "id":"US-AL",
    "state":"Alabama", 
    "industries" [ 
        {
           "industry":"All", 
           "categories" [
              {
                 "category":"Cable Related Services",
                  items [
                     {"itemid":"12290","item":"Basic Cable Services","answer":"Exempt","explanation":"The sale of these services is not subject to sales tax.","citation":"Ala. Code sec. 40-23-1; Ala. Code sec. 40-23-2"}, 
                     {"itemid":"12291","item":"Pay Per View","answer":"Exempt","explanation":"The sale of these services is not subject to sales tax.","citation":"Ala. Code sec. 40-23-1; Ala. Code sec. 40-23-2"}
                   ],
                 "category":"Sales Tax Holidays",
                 items [
                     {"itemid":"12524","item":"All Disaster Preparedness Supply","answer":"Exempt","explanation":"Alabama provides for an annual state sales tax holiday for severe weather preparedness items. Counties and municipalities are allowed to provide an exemption from local sales and use taxes from the same items during the same weekend as the state holiday.","citation":"Ala. Admin. Code r. 810-6-3-.66."}
                  ]
              }
           ],
           "industry":"Sales" ...
    "id":"US-AR",
    "state":"Arizona" ... 
]
```

I've tried using .map, .reduce, .filter ...

Using this example, I was able to get one level formatted, but not sure if this is the right method or if there is an easier way to accomplish this.

```
var grouped = utm.reduce((r, o) => {
  r[o.industry] = r[o.industry] || [];
  r[o.industry].push(o);
  return r;
}, {});
var rs = Object.keys(grouped).map(industry => ({ industry, categories: grouped[industry] }));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert flat array of objects into nested array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318150/convert-flat-array-of-objects-into-nested-array-of-objects)

Comment: Yes that did solve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a great answer to this from this SO post: [Convert flat array of objects into nested array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318150/convert-flat-array-of-objects-into-nested-array-of-objects/8318491#8318491)

I tried this and it does exactly what I was trying to do.

```
// Groups a flat array into a tree. 
// "data" is the flat array.
// "keys" is an array of properties to group on.
function groupBy(data, keys) { 

  if (keys.length == 0) return data;

  // The current key to perform the grouping on:
  var key = keys[0];

  // Loop through the data and construct buckets for
  // all of the unique keys:
  var groups = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  {
      var row = data[i];
      var groupValue = row[key];

      if (groups[groupValue] == undefined)
      {
          groups[groupValue] = new Array();
      }

      groups[groupValue].push(row);
  }

  // Remove the first element from the groups array:
  keys.reverse();
  keys.pop()
  keys.reverse();

  // If there are no more keys left, we're done:
  if (keys.length == 0) return groups;

  // Otherwise, handle further groupings:
  for (var group in groups)
  {
      groups[group] = groupBy(groups[group], keys.slice());
  }

  return groups;
}
```

Then I specify what fields I want to be grouped here:

```
var UtmDataByState = groupBy(utm, ["id","industry","category"]);
```

Worked great! Thanks Steve :)